# Unit testing a post method with a dynamic argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a post method in my web api controller that takes a dynamic argument

```
 public IEnumerable<Product> Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
    {
        int productId;
        try
        {
            productId = Convert.ToInt32(value.productId.Value);
        }
        catch
        {

            return null;
        }
        return _data.Products.Where(y => y.Id == productId).ToList();        
    }
```

I am trying to unit test this using the Moq frame work and this is what I have

```
 public void PostRequestWithSingleProductTest()

    {
        var reqBody = new {productId = 1};

        var reqObject = new Mock<HttpRequestMessage>();
        reqObject.Setup(rq => rq.ToString()).Returns(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqBody));

        var response = _productController.Post(reqObject.Object);


        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    }
```

The response is always null, and when I debug the test I can see that the value is passed is as {{productId:1}} but the compiler is not able to read this for some reason and it's throwing a **Microsoft.CSharp.Runtime.Binder Exception** .

I have marked the test assembly as a friend using assembly: **InternalsVisibleTo()**.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: I would also just like to point out that the Post method works as expected. I am just not sure how to unit test in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the method under test assumes that the `productId` is nullable, hence the `.Value`. The exception happens as the test passes an actual integer and not a nullable integer.

```
public void PostRequestWithSingleProductTest() {
    //Arrange
    int? productId = 1;
    var value = new { productId };

    //assuming _productController already created and injected with dependency

    //Act
    var response = _productController.Post(value);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
}
```

Ideally you should be using a strongly typed model

```
public class PostProductModel {
    [Required]
    public int productId { get; set; }
}
```

That would allow for the framework to do proper model binding

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]PostProductModel value) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        var result = _data.Products.Where(y => y.Id == value.productId).ToList();        
        return Ok(result);
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
 }
```

and greatly simplify the ability to unit test the target method.

```
public void PostRequestWithSingleProductTest() {
    //Arrange
    var value = new PostProductModel { productId = 1 };

    //assuming _productController already created and injected with dependency

    //Act
    var response = _productController.Post(value) as OkObjectResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I did not realise the role of nullable int here. I am still learning my way through web api / mvc etc.. using asp.net. Thanks for providing the right pattern for addressing this problem.